# Can not "report a problem" wants me to login but I am

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've already spent quite a bit of time trying fix the problem; to post on Developer Community; and to 'report a problem' through visual studio. The Developer Community website won't let me post directly, I get told that I have to get there through visual studio.

So when I help->send feedback->report a problem I get a dialog that says 'To send feedback, please sign in from Account settings'. I open account settings and I'm clearly logged in, I've never logged out. So there is no way to ask there about this problem for me.

I've run out of ways to ask Microsoft for help. After the upgrade to 16.8.3, I get:
`error MSB8070: Cannot find MSVC toolset version '14.27.29110'` This is only for a release build of console app. And now I find it is just one project, so, not a big deal. And, it had been a couple of weeks or so since I had opened that project, so it may not even be the upgrade.

So, the question is about being able to 'report a problem' and why can't I do that?

Comment: Is [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html) where you tried to report the problem online? It surely works from the browser, you just need an MS account to post. Maybe try a private/incognito session to bypass whatever cookies you may have saved.

Comment: Yes @dxiv, there. I'm logged in there also, I can see that in the upper right.I dropped 'report a problem->visual studio' and then get instructions to do it from VS. I'll log out, clear the cookies, and try it... EDIT: But I have to be logged in to post.

Comment: Try Report a Problem / C++ instead. And, yes, you need to be logged in. What I suggested was to do it in a fresh new private session, just in case there was something (mis)remembered in the browser.

Comment: As for the error, first thing make sure you have "*MSVC v142 ... (14.27)*" checked under Individual Components in the VS installer.

Comment: Hi @dxiv, Yes I can post to other than VS. But this I would believe is a VS problem. I checked, I have v14.28 checked. I take it they move that up on updates. And I can not find anything in the vcxproj files that might be out of line as to the toolset issue.

Comment: MSVC toolsets are arguably a C++ matter. Anyway, you have 14.28 checked but the error is about 14.27. Between the project files and the (verbose, if necessary) build output you should be able to narrow down what's missing.

Comment: Hi @dxiv, I found it. `VCToolsVersion` was locked down to 14.27 in the release of that project. At least now I know. I never set the toolset, so I'll write it off to a fluke. Thanks much for riding along on this. And yes, had it been critical, I would have to post to C++, just as well I didn't for this.

Comment: Good you had it figured out. Config-level toolset overrides are rather unusual, indeed.